# how do you change the color of a link once clicked, then change it back once another link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two links inside a div called div A. when link 1 is clicked a div with some info is shown (div B) and when the link 2 is clicked a different div(div C) is shown. This is done using jquery's show/hide.

I would like the color of the **selected** link to change and then return only **once the other link is clicked**. therefore highlighting which link the user is currently viewing.

Does anyone know how I go about achieving this link color change through Jquery or even PHP. Thank you. All help is greatly appreciated.

Javascript

```
    $("#link1").click(function() {
    $("#Div b").hide();
    $("Div c").show();
    });

    $("#link2").click(function() {
    $("#Div b").hide();
    $("#Div c").show();
    });
```

HTML

```
<div id="div a">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="links" id="link1"></a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="links" id="link2"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: You cannot use php to change the color of a link on click. It's a server-side scripting language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use CSS, either directly

```
$("#link1").click(function() 
{
    $("#Div b").hide();
    $("Div c").show();
    $(this).css('color', '#f00');
});

$("#link2").click(function() 
{
    $("#Div b").hide();
    $("#Div c").show();
    $(this).css('color', '#00f');
});
```

or by defining it in CSS

```
a.class1
{
    color: #f00;
}

a.class2
{
    color: #00f;
}
```

and then using it like this:

```
$("#link1").click(function() 
{
    $("#Div b").hide();
    $("Div c").show();
    $(this).toggleClass('class1');
});

$("#link2").click(function() 
{
    $("#Div b").hide();
    $("#Div c").show();
    $(this).toggleClass('class2');
});
```

Comment: `blue` and `red` are really bad names for CSS classes.

Answer (score 1):

The below solution relies on having ajax links. It will not work with standard links (meaning they do a round trip to the server and replace the page).

```
var i_color = '#FFOOOO';
var o_color = '#0000FF';

$('#div_a').delegate('.link', 'click', function(event){
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.css({color : i_color})
       .siblings()
       .css({ color : o_color })
})
```

To accomplish the feat in a static page environment you may wish to simply use the `:active` css pseudo selector like so.

```
// css file
.link:link {
  color : #0000FF;
}
.link:active {
  color : #FF0000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
$("#link1").css("color","yourcolor");
```

And then change it back when you call the other one.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
<style type='text/css'>
  .highlighted { color: red; }
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $("#link1").click(function() {     
    $("#Div b").hide();
    $("Div c").show();
    $('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');
    $(this).addClass('highlighted');  
  });      

  $("#link2").click(function() {
    $("#Div b").hide();
    $("#Div c").show();
    $('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');
    $(this).addClass('highlighted');  

  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a css class for the active link e.g 'active' and then assigning it to the correct link using jquery, while disabling it on the other. e.g:

css:

```
.active{
/* Some distinguishing style here */
}
```

js:

```
$("#link1").click(function() {
$("#Div b").hide();
$("Div c").show();
$('.active').removeClass('active');
$('#link1').addClass('active');
});

$("#link2").click(function() {
$("#Div b").hide();
$("#Div c").show();
$('.active').removeClass('active');
$('#link2').addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$("#link1").click(function() {
    $(".links").removeClass("special-color");
    $("#link1").addClass("special-color");
    $("#Divb").show();
    $("#Divc").hide();
});

$("#link2").click(function() {
    $(".links").removeClass("special-color");
    $("#link2").addClass("special-color");
    $("#Divb").hide();
    $("#Divc").show();
});
```

And then add something like this to your css:

```
a.special-color {
    color: #FF5E99; /* hot pink */
}
```

Also, IDs in HTML can't have spaces in them, so you should change your div IDs to something without spaces.